# Is there a ready-made library that does this widget in the picture

Tags: flutter

Is there a ready-made library that does this widget in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [syncfusion_flutter_sliders](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/install) or [RangeSlider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html) from Flutter's material library

Example of `syncfusion_flutter_sliders`:

```
SfRangeValues _values = SfRangeValues(3.0, 7.0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: SfRangeSlider.horizontal(
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: 10.0,
                    values: _values,
                    onChanged: (SfRangeValues newValues) {
                       setState(() {
                           _values = newValues;
                        });
                   },
              )
          )
      )
  );
}
```

Example of `rangeSlider`:

```
RangeValues values = RangeValues(1, 100);

RangeSlider(  
activeColor: Colors.red[700],
inactiveColor: Colors.red[300],
   min: 1,
    max: 100,
    values: values,
    onChanged: (values){
    setState(() {
      values =values;
    });
    }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) class.

```
Slider(
  value: _currentSliderValue,
  max: 100,
  divisions: 5,
  label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
  onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      _currentSliderValue = value;
    });
```